# どの程度コメントに丁寧な言葉遣いを求めますか？

Tags: 討議, コメント

以下のようなコメントに「失礼または不快」という通報がありました。

> なんでself.view.layerに追加してんの？　self.CaptureView.layerを親にしたいんじゃねーの？
>   AutoLayoutが親ビューのサイズを別のタイミングで変えてんのとレイヤにオートリサイズがないせいだろ。ずれてたのはboundsと親レイヤを間違えてたせい。サイズの変化に追従しないのは別の話だよ

他の投稿と比べると丁寧な言葉づかいとは言えないかもしれませんが、投稿者を非難したり暴言を吐くこともなく、きちんと技術的な指摘をしているように見えます。

皆さんはこのコメントについてどう思いますか？

Answer (score 20):

人によって感じ方は異なるので一概には言えませんが、丁寧語と比べて不快と感じる人が多くなる可能性は高いと思います。
また、場合によっては質問者を萎縮させてしまい、結果として離脱に繋がってしまうケースも起こり得るような気がします（「あそこで質問するのは怖い」的な）。

対面や知り合いとのやり取りであれば該当ケースのような言葉遣いでも問題ないと思いますが、文面のみでのやり取りになるので、通常よりも少し気を使う必要があるように思います。

結論として、不要な衝突を避ける意味でも、ある程度丁寧な言葉遣いを心掛けた方が良い（無難）だろう、というのが個人的な意見です。

Answer (score 8):

必要以上に丁寧で伝わらないより、ちょっとくらい粗暴でもちゃんと的確なこと書いてある方が嬉しい。それに丁寧に書こうとすると、必要以上に文字数も増えるような気がします...
なので、個人的には掲題の言葉遣いは十分許容範囲内だと思います。

ま、今回のような通報を避けたいのなら、最低限の注意は必要かと思います。でも、やっぱし、通報するほどの言葉遣いじゃ無いような...(－ω－;)

Comment: +1: 当該コメントの文体は口語的／フランクではあると感じますが、"失礼"で通報に値するとは思えませんでした。丁寧語が望ましいとは思いますが、慣れない妙な敬語をこねくり回すくらいなら、この程度は許容してほしいなーと思います。

Comment: 日本語のネイティブじゃないため、「失礼」は非常に判断しにくいです。前の会社のマネージャがそれを言ったら腹が立ちますが、頭の良い同僚なら全然大丈夫だと思います。丁寧のレベルのみではなく、立場によって感じ方が変わると思います。ネットで立場がわからないので、どうやって「失礼」を判断するのかな？

Comment: @yohjp どういった状況を想定しているのかちょっと分からないのですが、丁寧語に慣れようとして試行錯誤しているユーザーに「妙な敬語をこねくり‌​回す」というのはやや失礼じゃないでしょうか。慣れないうちは仕方ないと思います。

Answer (score 6):

礼儀を欠いた話し方をされていますから分類としては「失礼」に当たるコメントになると思いますが、内容が有用である場合は削除しないでいただきたいです。

日本語サイトとして質の高さを保つには、最低限の礼儀や丁寧語は必要だと思います。ただ、Q&Aサイトとしては、有用な情報を残すほうが目的に適っているのではないでしょうか。

私個人の感覚としましては、ワイルド過ぎる口調あるいはシンプル過ぎる口調であっても、明らかな暴言要素が無く、内容が的を射ていれば許容範囲内だと思います。自分が質問者や読者である場合には許容範囲どころか、口調はどうあれ有用な情報をいただけることは心底ありがたいです。

ですが実際、敬語を使わないという点ですでに侮辱的に思えたり不快に感じたりする方々も少なくないと思います。ルールでなくてもマナーの範囲、という考えもあります。私自身、引用のコメントを不快とまでは感じませんが、違和感は覚えます。

敬語を使える方々があえてワイルドな話し方に走るようなことはあって欲しくないですし、サイト全体としては丁寧な言葉遣いでやりとりする場であっていただきたいです。ただ、丁寧でないという理由だけで違反にするのは厳し過ぎるような気がします。

情報が良質であれば、今回の例程度の場合でしたら、言葉遣いの多様性に門戸を開いておいても良いのではないでしょうか。